# winetricks wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "" error

Tags: wine, winetricks

im trying to launch a dotnet app with wine and need to install dotnet on my prefix. i use `WINEPREFIX="/home/amiroof/WinePrefix/" winetricks` but i get an error saying

```
Executing mkdir -p /home/amiroof
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
WINEPREFIX INFO:
Drive C: total 28
drwxrwxr-x  7 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 ProgramData
drwxrwxr-x  6 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 Program Files
drwxrwxr-x  6 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 Program Files (x86)
drwxrwxr-x  4 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 users
drwxrwxr-x 18 amiroof amiroof 4096 Jul 19 07:04 windows

Registry info:
/home/amiroof/WinePrefix//system.reg:#arch=win64
/home/amiroof/WinePrefix//user.reg:#arch=win64
/home/amiroof/WinePrefix//userdef.reg:#arch=win64
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
warning: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "" 
------------------------------------------------------
```

i tried deleting the prefix and changing its location but didn't worked.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; these let us understand what software stack you're using & are a starting point.

Comment: It's happening everywhere in Winetricks when wine is compiled with the `--enable-archs=i386,x86_64` flag. Which is now on various Linux distros, incl. but not limited to Ubuntu, Debian, Zorin OS, SparkyLinux,... This is due to a bug in Winetricks, which is still not solved. And expect a wine64 binary being present, which is no longer the case anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a problem for more than just you. Winetricks has an open bug about the issue right now, although the discussion there seems to be unclear as to whether it's a problem with wine, winetricks, or just how it's packaged for Ubuntu.

https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/2084

Comment: This issue is closed, but it's definitely not solved! https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/2119 is also closed.

Comment: The root-cause seems to be that Winetricks is trying to use wine64 binary, which is not always present on distros, since you can compile Wine in a new way resulting into a special `wine` wrapper script instead. However, winetricks is currently not handling this well for 64-bit bottles!